# Typescript Backbone View Events do not fire

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, typescript, backbone-views, backbone-events

I'm trying to make a simple view to test with backbone. I've started with events, but no one fires. Why ?
I've made already other things with backbone like routing etc. without problems. Thanks for your time.
My backbone definitions are from [-> this source <-](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped)

```
module Views {
export class MenuView extends Backbone.View {
    constructor(viewOptions?: Backbone.ViewOptions) {

        super(viewOptions);
    }

    el = document.body;
    events = {
        "click #Btn-Start": "navigate",
        "click #Btn-Software": "navigate",
        "click #Btn-Anderes": "navigate",
        "click #Btn-Impressum": "navigate"
    };

    initialize() {
        console.log("initialize"); // fire
    }

    render() {
        console.log("render"); // not fire
    }

    navigate() {
        console.log("navigate"); // not fire
    }
}
```

}

```
<body>
    <div id="Menu">
        <div id="Btn-Start"></div>
        <div id="Btn-Software"></div>
        <div id="Btn-Anderes"></div>
        <div id="Btn-Impressum"></div>
    </div>
<body>
```

EDIT: Tried routes with the route(name: string, callback: function) and the routes as object.
It seems to work with a function reference but not as string in the routes object. Maybe there is a way to declare it in the view like these.

Comment: Where and when do you instantiate your `MenuView`? Because you should do it when the DOM is loaded...

Comment: @nemesv document.ready

Comment: Have you referenced jquery? And you can try with `el = "body"`. And also the typescirpt `MenuView extends Backbone.View` is not exactly the same with the Backbone way: `var MenuView = Backbone.View.extend({` ...

Comment: @nemesv yeep jquery is referenced.. $el = $("body") doesn't work ether

Comment: did anybody tried the events of the views with backbone and typescript ?

Comment: I've never mentioned `$`... You should try to change `el = document.body;` to `el = "body;"` no `$` anywhere.

Comment: changed my backbone def to el: any and tried it. do not help.

Comment: It might help if you post the javascript that is being generated from the TS above - that way someone who has worked with backbone in JS may be able to spot an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the setElement function inside the ctor instead of el object.

Answer (score 2):

All answers are not correct answers.

you need to use the `getter`, because this one is set to the prototype, while usual properties are set **after** the parent ctor is called - that´s too late.

use this for proper functionality

```
export class View extends Backbone.View {
    get events() { 
        return { 
            "click .button" : "myEvent"
        }
    }
}
```

the same you have to do for `Collection` when you are setting the `model` property. Otherwise Backbone will use the default `Backbone.Model` Type

Comment: In 2015, this produces a compile error like this: error TS2423: Class 'View<T>' defines instance member function 'events', but extended class 'BaseView<T>' defines it as instance member accessor.

Comment: This worked for me without the get keyword at the beginning, and defining the return type. `events(): Backbone.EventsHash {`

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue with initialization sequence between Backbone and typescript constructor. Constructor is generated as

`_super.call(this, attributes);
      this.events = {
        "click a.back": "back",
        "click a.changeDate": "changeDate"
      };`
>

but Backbone hooks events (and call initialize) from _super.call

```
var View = Backbone.View = function(options) {
   this.cid = _.uniqueId('view');
   this._configure(options || {});
   this._ensureElement();
   this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
   this.delegateEvents();
};
```

Backbone expects that View object is fully initialized by the time when constructor is called which is not the case.

The best solution I found so far is to use Backbone.extend instead of class

`export var MyView = Backbone.View.extend`

Issue 1098 in typescript project on codeplex

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your **el** to "#Menu"

```
module Views {
export class MenuView extends Backbone.View {
    constructor(viewOptions?: Backbone.ViewOptions) {

        super(viewOptions);
    }

    el = "#Menu";
```

Comment: Make sure your script is executed after the DOM is loaded. And your #el exists when creating the view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Basically, all the events and any preliminary instantiation/pre-processing goes in the `Constructor` instead.

The reason why `render()` and `navigate()` are not firing is because, the events are not properly hooked up.

```
module Views {
    export class MenuView extends Backbone.View {
        constructor(viewOptions?: Backbone.ViewOptions) {
            super(viewOptions);

            // Any initialization goes in the constructor.
            this.el = document.body;
            this.events = {
                 "click #Btn-Start": "navigate",
                 "click #Btn-Software": "navigate",
                 "click #Btn-Anderes": "navigate",
                 "click #Btn-Impressum": "navigate"
            };

            // Precompile and cache the template.
            this.template = _.template($('#template').html());
            console.log("initialize");
       }
       render() {
            console.log("render");
            return this;
       }
       navigate() {
            console.log("navigate");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't help ether. have already my own answer. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

### file:  requirejsConfig.ts

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery',
        underscore: 'bower_components/underscore/underscore',
        backbone: 'bower_components/backbone/backbone',
        test: 'test'
    }
});

require(['test'], function(Test: any){
    new Test.test; 
});
```

### file: test.ts

```
/// <reference path="../typings/tsd.d.ts" />

import Backbone = require('backbone');
import $ = require( 'jquery');


export class Test extends Backbone.View<Backbone.Model> {
   events(): Backbone.EventsHash
    { 
        return { 
            'click': 'showResult'            
        }
    }
    constructor( options?: any )
    {
        super(options);
        this.setElement( $( '.test-el' ), true );        
    }    
   protected showResult(): void 
   {
        console.log( 'show result ' );    
   }
}
```