# Running BackboneJs events in Typescript

Tags: backbone.js, typescript

I'm writing a Backbone program in Typescript, in which I am not able to initialize any events. Here's a test class that I've created to fix the problem. The function `start()` is not being called when the div is clicked on.

```
class TestView extends Backbone.View{

    events = {
        "click #testDiv" : "start"
    }

    start(){
        console.log("Clicked");
    }

    constructor(options?){
        super(options);
    }

    render(){
        $root.html(getNewDiv("testDiv"));
        $("#testDiv").css("height", 100).css("width", 100).css("background-color", "green");
        console.log("Rendered");
        return this;
    }
}

function getNewDiv(id:string) {
    return "<div id = \"" + id + "\"></div>"
}

new TestView().render();
```

Here's the console output:

```
Rendered
```

---

Here's the backbone typescript definition that I'm using:

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/backbone/backbone.d.ts

---

Here's the CDN location for backboneJS

Minified : http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.0/backbone-min.js

Non-Minified : http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.0/backbone.js

I'm concerned if my syntax is right or this has something to do with the Typescript definition of Backbone.

**UPDATE**

The answer shown by Kevin Peel below is throwing an error, because in the Typescript definition file, "events" is defined as a function ( eg. events()). If I just create an "events" function, I get the error - "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'off'". If I use the getter method (eg. get events(){}), then nothing really happens on actually firing the event.

```
Using delegate Events
```

I tried to use the `delegateEvents()` function in Backbone.View which creates an error:

```
constructor(options:any, question:Question, div:JQuery) {
        this.delegateEvents({
           "click" : "clicked"
        });
    }
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'off' backbone.js:1082
h.extend.undelegateEvents backbone.js:1082
h.extend.delegateEvents backbone.js:1059
```

Comment: @JqueryLearner I'm not sure what you mean. This code is written in Typescript. Are you familiar with Typescript?

Comment: @JqueryLearner Try this: http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/docs/backbone.html. Please don't use the commenting section for comments unrelated to the stated problem. Thanks.

Comment: Does #testDiv exist when you instantiate your view? I'm not sure what `getNewDiv` is or does...

Comment: @KevinPeel Thanks for pointing that out. getNewDiv generates new div html with the specified id. Please see updated code.

Comment: Is `$root` the same as `$el`? because in order for the click event to be fired the `#testDiv` must be a descendent of the views `el`

Comment: What about if you create an evens function that returns an events object? for example `events = function () { return {"click #testDiv" : "start"  } `

Comment: @Jack This syntax `events = function(){...}` is not allowed in Typescript. You have to do a `events() {
        return {
            "click #testDiv": "start"
        }
    }` which creates `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'off'` - and prevents the page from rendering at all.

Comment: OK, to be honest I haven't used typescript. What about [@kevin's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1160937/kevin-peel) [original suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47560cd8-cc66-44da-a2db-449da77b5deb/view-source) of calling delegate events in your render method?

Comment: Honestly, I don;t really know what "delegate events" mean. Can you specify/elaborate?

Comment: There is a backbone method [delegateEvents](http://www.backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) which you can call in your view to *redelegate* your events or pass in a different events hash. If you call it in your render method the events should be bound then even if they weren't when the view was initialized. For example in your render method you can call `this.delegateEvents()` (optionally passing in a events object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with where TypeScript defines the events. When you define events like this:

```
class TestView extends Backbone.View {
    events = {
        "click #testDiv": "start"
    }
    // ...
}
```

What TypeScript does is attaches `events` as a property *after* initializing the instance. So when Backbone is initializing the view, `events` haven't yet been attached, so Backbone isn't able to bind them.

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a nice way to get TypeScript to assign `events` to the prototype, so you need to hack around it in some way.

The absolute easiest way is by setting the events on the prototype yourself:

```
class TestView extends Backbone.View {
    // Get rid of the events declaration in here
    // ...
}

TestView.prototype.events = {
    "click #testDiv": "start"
}
```

A second possible way to get around the issue is using the `getter` functionality of TypeScript as suggested in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896087/typescript-backbone-view-events-do-not-fire/18883245#18883245).

Finally, a third way would be to bind your events each time you render. This is another easy way to get around the TypeScript problem, but it might not be the best solution if the view gets rendered many times.

```
class TestView extends Backbone.View{
    events = {
        "click #testDiv" : "start"
    }

    // ...

    render(){
        $root.html(getNewDiv("testDiv"));
        // Here is where you'll bind the events using Backbone's delegateEvents
        this.delegateEvents();
        $("#testDiv").css("height", 100).css("width", 100).css("background-color", "green");
        console.log("Rendered");
        return this;
    }
}

// ...

new TestView().render();
```

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference, since backbone binds the events  using [event delegation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) to the root `el` and not to the actual element. Have a look at this [line in the source](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1084)

Comment: Turns out it's a TypeScript issue. Rewrote the answer to address the real problem.

Comment: What about delegating the events in the initialize function?

Comment: Unfortunately they don't exist yet by the time `initialize` is called. TypeScript doesn't set the `events` property until after it calls the parent constructor of its class. In this case, that constructor is Backbone.View where `initialize` (and `delegateEvents`) is called.

Comment: Understood, though your original suggestion of delegating the events in the render method should then work...

Comment: Yeah, delegating in the render method does indeed work. However I removed the whole answer since the explanation around the solution was completely wrong... I ended up with the answer above since I thought it might be best to avoid delegating every single time the view is rendered. But you're right, it's certainly another viable solution.

Comment: @KevinPeel and Jack. Thank you both of you. I really appreciate your effort. However, my problem remains unsolved. Please see update above in the question.

Comment: @EternallyCurious I readded an example on how to hopefully fix the issue using `delegateEvents` per @Jack's suggestion above.

Comment: @KevinPeel I'm still getting this `error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'off'`. Although this could be a problem  if the CDN is serving an old version of backbone. What url do you use for backbone?

Comment: @EternallyCurious This is kind of a different issue at this point. When you used that new code where you called `delegateEvents` in the `constructor`, TypeScript no longer calls `super` which is the constructor for `Backbone.View`. This causes all kinds of issues. Long story short, put `super();` into your TypeScript file above your `this.delegateEvents(...);` call.

Comment: @KevinPeel Huh? delagateevents() is to be called in `render()` which is  what you've shown and what makes sense. The above problem happened bacause of an outdated version of jQuery which I fixed. By the way, do  you know how to access the calling html element and its attributes and current status values? Assuming the click event is happening on some kind of an input element like a checkbox.

Comment: @EternallyCurious Ahh, sorry, I didn't realize you were having the same issue in `render`. To get the calling HTML element, look at the event passed in to `start`. Define `start` this way, `start(ev) {`, then the HTML element will be `ev.target` within the function.

Answer (score 1):

I know is an old question but there is now another possibility, using es7 decorators, similar to what angular2 does:

```
 @component({
   events: {
     "click #testDiv" : "start"
   }
 })
 class TestView extends Backbone.View{
   start(){
     console.log("Clicked");
   }
   render(){
     // ...
   }
 }
```

Decorator file

```
export function component(definition: any) {
  return function (constructor: any) {
    Object.assign(constructor.prototype, definition)
  }
}
```

This way, all properties defined in the component decorator will be attached to the class prototype and will be available at instantiation time.

---

Another option besides using a class/constructor decorator could be to use a method decorator on the `preinitialize` method if you wish to have all the code inside the class braces like this:

```
 class TestView extends Backbone.View {
   @component({
     events: {
       "click #testDiv" : "start"
     }
   })
   preinitialize(){}

   start(){
     console.log("Clicked");
   }
   render(){
     // ...
   }
 }
```

Decorator file

```
export function component(definition: any) {
  return function (target: Object, methodName: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<Function>) {
    Object.assign(target, definition)
  }
}
```